# Microphone not working in Ubuntu Natty

Tags: linux, microphone, ubuntu-11.04, alsa

**Problem:**
I can hear myself speak in the mic but Ubuntu is not recording/capturing the sound.

**Actions Taken:**
I followed all the steps listed here for the Alsa update script

I've also tried changing my `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.config` file with the following configurations one at a time.

```
options snd-hda-intel model=auto
options snd-hda-intel model=acer
options snd-hda-intel model=3stack
options snd-hda-intel model=generic
```

**Other info:**
Im running Ubuntu Natty Narwahl dual booted with Win7 on a Acer Aspire 5542G laptop.

```
**cat /proc/asound/card0/codec#* | grep Codec**

Codec: Realtek ALC888
Codec: Conexant ID 2c06

**aplay -l**

**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: SB [HDA ATI SB], device 0: ALC888 Analog [ALC888 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: SB [HDA ATI SB], device 1: ALC888 Digital [ALC888 Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

**ls -l /dev/snd**

drwxr-xr-x  2 root root       80 2011-06-21 20:51 by-path
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  8 2011-06-21 20:51 controlC0
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116, 11 2011-06-21 20:51 controlC1
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  7 2011-06-21 20:51 hwC0D0
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  6 2011-06-21 20:51 hwC0D1
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116, 10 2011-06-21 20:51 hwC1D0
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  5 2011-06-21 21:34 pcmC0D0c
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  4 2011-06-21 21:56 pcmC0D0p
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  3 2011-06-21 21:34 pcmC0D1p
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  2 2011-06-21 20:51 pcmC0D2c
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  9 2011-06-21 21:34 pcmC1D3p
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  1 2011-06-21 21:34 seq
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116, 33 2011-06-21 20:51 timer
```

My capture settings are 'on' in alsamixer as in they are in red with the words CAPTURE underneath it.

Comment: What recording software are you trying this with?

Comment: sound recording and skype

Comment: Is "sound recording" the name of the software?

Comment: Sorry I meant sound recorder